# Unable to center icon

Tags: html, css

Trying to center this Facebook icon but just can't.

```html
<div style="float: center; display: inline-block">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bentinson.a/"><img src="images/red-fb.png" height="36px" width="36px" alt="" title=""></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Center it based on what? the floating inline block div? What's the intention here? What is not working? It's hard to tell what is not centering because from the code above, your anchor is already centered relative to its container. You need provide more context. Definitely need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align` to center the image

Try this :

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bentinson.a/"><img src="images/red-fb.png" height="36px" width="36px" alt="" title=""></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: wow ... why down vote ?... anyone explain really appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The div itself will span the entire container it is in and therefore you want to center the contents thus you can do `text-align` to center the image.

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bentinson.a/"><img src="images/red-fb.png" height="36px" width="36px" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```